# Netlogo - How to replicate an experiment adjusting one parameter using import-world?

Tags: replication, netlogo

I have a simulation in which agents move around the physical grid exchange ideas on topics with their neighbours. I have conducted a study and would like to replicate it perfectly but with only one modification - a slightly adjusted "transfer" parameter so that ideas exchange at a slower rate.

To try and get a perfect replication I have used the export/import world procedure. When I re-run a simulation from tick 0 with an imported world and none of the parameters are changed, the model is identical. I get the same output, agents move and have the same interactions and everything is identical. Great

However, when I re-run the simulation from tick zero with the same imported world, but slightly adjust one paramater (transfer_rate), the agents move around the physical space differently, meet different agents to the original simulation and ultimately I get different results.

Perhaps by adjusting one parameter the pseudorandom number has altered somehow? Does anyone know of any way of having everything perfectly controlled and constant with the exception of this one transfer_rate parameter adjustment? Perhaps there is a simple solution.

Thank you for your time everyone.

Comment: A little more information about the effect of the transfer-rate parameter would be useful. If a different rate leads to a different number of interactions, then this would explain the difference in model dynamics, because more or fewer random numbers are generated at that point in the simulation and therefore the generator is at a different state.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. Don't you _want_ something different to happen as a result of adjusting a parameter?

Comment: Depending on your meaning, your question may actually be nonsensical. See http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Behavior-space-random-seed-and-four-kernels-tp4869654p4869661.html

Comment: Hi JenB and Seth. Thank you so much for your reply. Having read up on with-local-randomness, and then reading your helpful link Seth, I got on to a link of a link https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/conversations/topics/6744

Comment: This was really helpful, and now I realize that the random seed ultimately works a replay button. By changing any parameter (even by a small degree) this will impact on operations which use the random number generator. This in turn means that your next procedure is using a different random number generator and this continues.

Comment: The with-local-randomness seems to be very useful, but my model is extremely long, so I might not have too much success. Either way I will give it a try and use it anywhere I use the 'ask' 'report' primitives and display output. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities might help. You could try `with-local-randomness` to isolate the random processes that are affected by the change in the transfer_rate. Alternatively, one simulation doesn't really tell you anything anyway, so you could move away from trying to exactly match the dynamics and simply run multiple simulations and then compare the two sets of simulations.